# Display list of routes/controllers in Rails application as UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I was working on Rails years ago (I think it's Rails 4 then), I vaguely remember there was a debug webpage UI that could be accessed during development that showed the list of controllers/routes in a Rails application when it's running. Something like `http://localhost:4000/routes` or something.

However, I can't seem to find despite searching hard for it. Does anyone know how I can find it these days and whether it's still available?

Comment: Try this one `/rails/info/routes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

Try with a 3000 port number - should work fine.

You can also call `rails routes` from your terminal.

Comment: I forgot to add - here's a link to the documentation that details these commands and some extra switches.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!